# What is the way to manage UI messaging for PHP / jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, user-interface, message

I've been tasked with setting up a user interface to manage our success & error messaging for our web application, which has a PHP/MySQL backend. We use a lot of jQuery on the frontend.

Currently all the messages are in a php array with a descriptive name as key and the message as value. We echo them out to a jQuery message popup plugin through json. We've also echo'd the array out with json_encode to a var to make messages accessible through js files.

I was contemplating throwing the array into a db table with some columns like: `'id','editable'(boolean),'org_id'(int),'title'(varchar),'message'(varchar),'description'(varchar),'module_event'(varchar, for value, maybe json), 'status'(bolean for active/inactive)` and just create the array from there.

**THE QUESTION:** Do any any packages for something like this exist? If not, please make any suggestions based on info provided. Thanks!

I'd like to get suggestions of existing solutions or best way to manage the situation. Would LOVE to automate some of this if possible. These success & error messages are things along the lines of "This record has been saved", "Username or Password incorrect" etc.. (my manager, not a programmer, wants the ability to review the messages in web UI, see where they would appear and under which circumstances. He also wants the ability to create and edit these messages - He understands a programmer would have to implement or remove the messages in the codebase, and he is OK with that - any ideas around that point are welcomed though). Note: some messages do have tokens in them which we switch out, like @@username@@.

Also, one more point, they wanted the ability for the customer to alter messages for their organization. That's where I was thinking if message record is flagged as editable, they could create a new record that has `org_id` of current org, and it would override the global, which would have a `null` or empty value.

Comment: Put your errors in the db, and you can easily manage them. Call  them by id via ajax, and return 'name' and 'description'. By doing this you could easily set up an admin dashboard to edit names and descriptions of desired error messages. However, being able to create new error messages may be impossible. I dont know how you could create an error message through UI, there would be no functions to throw any new erros?

Comment: @Mark I was thinking through UI, user (possibly QA or manager) could create message & description, do an insert to DB, and have `status` = 0, maybe shoot an email notification to dev to review and add where necessary...change status to 1 and it would be added to array, status may not be necessary though, as you mention, it couldn't appear until we add it to function...